# How to display dropdown list from related entities in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I want to create a drop-down list from two related entities "Category" and "sub-category".
Under symfony I know how to create it from a single entity at a time but I have not managed to do so in a way that in the drop-down list each category displays the subcategories that belongs to it as indicated in the figure bellow.

[image: dropdown list figure]

Comment: There's a `group_by` option for ChoiceType, which will be helpful here. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#group-by  You didn't provide any code so I'm not able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give arrays to your 'choices' field, each one representing a category.

```
$builder->add('stockStatus', ChoiceType::class, array(
'choices' => array(
    'Main Statuses' => array(
        'Yes' => 'stock_yes',
        'No' => 'stock_no',
    ),
    'Out of Stock Statuses' => array(
        'Backordered' => 'stock_backordered',
        'Discontinued' => 'stock_discontinued',
    ),
),
```

));

you can find more information here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#grouping-options